# Google sheets, conditional formatting, vlookup, dynamic range

Tags: vlookup

Google sheets recognizes this as a valid formula in conditional formatting because it gets a blue box - =vlookup($F11,indirect("Math Guts!F11:BJ"),{11,13,15},0)=indirect("Math Guts!P$10").  HOWEVER, it always takes the first value inside the {}.  Is this truly a valid formula? Are {} allowed in conditional formatting like they are in google sheets formulas? How do I get it to recognizes the {13}, then {15}??  *Note - I'm confident the range in conditional formatting is correct.